# Check if a column exists in a table?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exists

I have to check if a column exists in a table, if it does than I have to delete it and if it doesn't exist I have to add it, and only in vb.

I've read something about `DataColumnCollection.Contains`- for checking if the column exists, but I don't really understand how to use it. any help is useful.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.aspx

Comment: Google would have found you this answer. In fact, if I Google your thread title and append 'vb.net' to the end the first 3-4 results are direct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove it from the `DataTable`, first check whether it exists with `Contains` and then use `Remove` Try:

```
If myDataTable.Columns.Contains("columnName") Then
    myDataTable.Columns.Remove("columnName");
End If
```